# PHP - Loop custom post type categories within jQuery Tabs

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have a custom post type called 'Products'

Within products there is a custom field called 'Sub Category' (selsubcat) which contains 14 different categories.

These categories are; CAM / REC / ACC / SWH / NET / MON / HDMI / ENC / SIGNS / PIR / WIFI / POLE / SOUND.

What I am trying to do display all the products within a different tab, where the tabs are the sub categories, and each tab will display the products for that category. At the moment I've defined the `meta_value` as 'CAM' and this is displaying all the products with the category 'CAM' within the `#tabs-1` div - which is correct.

I now need to somehow loop each category and display the products in the other 13 tabs.

So `#tabs-1` will show all the products for the category 'CAM', `#tabs-2` will show all the products for the category 'REC' and so on...

Here is what I have at the moment:-

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php
        if( have_rows('sub_category', 'option') ): $cat_increment = 1;
            while ( have_rows('sub_category', 'option') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <!-- Tab Sub Categories -->
                <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $cat_increment; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('category_name'); ?></a></li>
            <?php $cat_increment++; endwhile;
        else : endif;
        ?>
    </ul>

    <?php 

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'     => 'products',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_key'      => 'selsubcat',
        'meta_value'    => 'CAM'
    ));

    if( $posts ): ?>


    <div id="tabs-1">   

        <table id="table-products" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden">id</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Total Cost</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden">id</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Total Cost</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>                        

                <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

                    setup_postdata( $post );

                    ?>

                    <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="hidden"><?php the_ID(); ?></td>
                              <td><span class="product-image" style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);"></span></td>
                              <td><?php the_field('code'); ?></td>
                              <td><?php the_field('description'); ?></td>
                              <td><?php the_field('cost_price'); ?></td>
                              <td><input type="text" /></td>
                              <td><input type="text" /></td>
                              <td><input type="button" class="add-row" name="add-row" value="Add"></td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>

                <?php $product_increment++; endforeach; ?>

            </table>    

        </div>


        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I'm stuck at this point so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can fire query only by `'meta_key'=> 'selsubcat'` without `meta_value` `and you will get all subcategories. Then you should loop outside you tab with some increment(maybe a name of category or numeric id) something like this:

```
<?php 
foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div id="tabs-<?php the_ID(); ?>">   
        <table id="table-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden"><?php the_ID(); ?></td>
                    <td><span class="product-image" style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);"></span></td>
                    <td><?php the_field('code'); ?></td>
                    <td><?php the_field('description'); ?></td>
                    <td><?php the_field('cost_price'); ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="add-row" name="add-row" value="Add"></td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
            <?php $product_increment++; endforeach; ?>
        </table>    
      </div>
</div>
```